# Angular: Animate text changing

Tags: css, angular

I have a silly question, but frankly, I couldn't find any solution for my problem.

I have Angular (4) app, on the home page, I have heading text. I want that each 2 sec the heading text will change (to another sentence from some predefined set of heading sentences). The change will be animated. (eq. fade in/out)

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Have you tried something so far ? Because that does not sound like a big deal. Something like a `<span ngIf*="someText" @myAnimation>{{someText}}</span>` and alternating `someText="foo"`, wait animation end, then `someText=null` wait animation end and finaly `someText="bar"`. I guess you can even do avoid using the `someText=null` just with animations.

Comment: [Angular animations guide](https://angular.io/guide/animations)

Comment: Maybe not without setting to `null` actually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the solution that you can to try:
Html:

```
<header>
<h1 class="header-text"></h1>
</header>
```

Css:

```
.header-text:after {
  content:"";
  animation: spin 6s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes spin {
  0% { content:"header1"; }
  30% { content:"header2"; }
  60% { content:"header3"; }
  100% { content:"header4"; }
}
```